# Flutter application failed build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, dart

I have an issue where I'm unable to run my Flutter application on any iOS device.

I'm running my project in Xcode 11 and below is the issue I get

```
Showing Recent Issues

Build target Runner of project Runner with configuration Debug
error: /Users/jaserjsk/Development/GitHub/Middle-East-Cuisine/me_cuisine_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
error: /Users/jaserjsk/Development/GitHub/Middle-East-Cuisine/me_cuisine_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
error: /Users/jaserjsk/Development/GitHub/Middle-East-Cuisine/me_cuisine_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
error: /Users/jaserjsk/Development/GitHub/Middle-East-Cuisine/me_cuisine_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
error: /Users/jaserjsk/Development/GitHub/Middle-East-Cuisine/me_cuisine_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
error: /Users/jaserjsk/Development/GitHub/Middle-East-Cuisine/me_cuisine_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
error: /Users/jaserjsk/Development/GitHub/Middle-East-Cuisine/me_cuisine_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
error: /Users/jaserjsk/Development/GitHub/Middle-East-Cuisine/me_cuisine_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
warning: The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

I have no ide what this mean or how to fix it.
Please help